# MongoDB: How to find a document by an id inside a nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, embedded-documents

Given a collection like this:..

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a621"),
    "name": "Joe",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a655"),
        "default": true,
        "status" : "approved",
        "activationTime" : ISODate("2013-05-03T14:37:15.025Z")
      },
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a688"),
        "default": true,
        "status" : "approved",
        "activationTime" : ISODate("2014-06-03T14:37:15.025Z")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("9546329a470079850084a622"),
    "name": "Jimmy",
    "surname": "Brown",
    "accounts": [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470790850084a651"),
        "default": true,
        "status" : "suspended",
        "activationTime" : ISODate("2015-02-03T14:37:15.025Z")
      },
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470019850084a611"),
        "default": true,
        "status" : "approved",
        "activationTime" : ISODate("2015-04-03T14:37:15.025Z")
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

... how do I find a document by `accounts.N._id`? I've tried this...

```
db.users.find(
  {},
  {
    "accounts": 0, "accounts": {
      "$elemMatch": { "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470019850084a611"), "default": true }
    }
  }
)
```

... but it does't work since I get only the `_id` of all the documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a621") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("9546329a470079850084a622") }
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

The result that I actually need is something like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("9546329a470079850084a622"),
  "name": "Jimmy",
  "surname": "Brown"
}
```

For instance, I need to find by `accounts.N._id` but without showing the nested document itself.

Comment: is there any way to update status of Same object?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents):

> When the field holds an embedded document, a query can either specify
>   an exact match on the embedded document or specify a match by
>   individual fields in the embedded document using the dot notation.

```
db.coll.find({
   "accounts._id" :ObjectId("5546329a470019850084a611")
})
```

If you need to output only the part of an array where you have your _id you need to use [dollar in projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitations)

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  from the
>   query results to contain only the first element matching the query
>   document.

and your query would look like:

```
db.coll.find({
   "accounts._id" :ObjectId("5546329a470019850084a611")
}, {
   "accounts.$.": 1
})
```

**P.S.** if you need the output like in your modified questions, use this:

```
db.coll.find({
   "accounts._id" :ObjectId("5546329a470019850084a611")
 }, {
   accounts : 0
 })
```

Comment: Maybe it helps someone: to cast the `id` `string` to `ObjectId`, one must import `const objectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID`

Answer (score 7):

The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition.

In your case:

```
db.users.find({'_id': ObjectId('5546329a470000850084a621')}, {accounts: {$elemMatch: {_id: ObjectId('5546329a470000850084a655')}}})
```

Refer: [Mongo Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch)

Comment: It includes example with description and links to that referred page and glossary. So, that person who asked this question can see other MongoDB terminologies.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$elemMatch` in criteria and use `$` positional operator in project as below :

```
db.users.find({
  "accounts": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "_id": ObjectId("5546329a470019850084a611"),
      "default": true
    }
  }
}, {
  "accounts.$._id": 1 // "accounts.$": 1 also works
}).pretty()
```