# MongoDB: How to get data of a nested object searching by a key value?

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm learning MongoDB and trying to retrieve objects by a specific key value using MongoDB client.

I have this data:

```
{
    "type": "products",
    "products": {
        "Intel® Core™ i9-9980XE Extreme Edition": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 2457,
            "catalog_id": "1"
        },
        "Intel® Core™ i9-9980HK": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 1548,
            "catalog_id": "1"
        },
        "AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2990WX": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 500,
            "catalog_id": "2"
        },
        "Baikalel Ectronics BE-M1000": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 128,
            "catalog_id": "3"
        },
        "GeForce RTX 2080 Ti": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 2048,
            "catalog_id": "5"
        }   
    }
}
```

I've find out how to access to data in nested objects:

```
db.shop.findOne( { type : "products" }).products["GeForce RTX 2080 Ti"].price
```

But I'm a little bit confused how to get all hested objects filtred by `"catalog_id": "1"`

When I use

```
db.shop.find( { type : "products" }, {"catalog_id": "1"})
```

MongoDB client shows only id of the main object.

Answer (score 1):

`db.shop.find( { "products.catalog_id": "1"})`

Similiar question [MongoDB: How to find a document by an id inside a nested document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044792/mongodb-how-to-find-a-document-by-an-id-inside-a-nested-document)

Answer (score 0):

The data you have shared here looks like a single object only, with having two keys type and products. So your query is matching this object and returning you the object correctly. You need to parse it afterwards. Mongo query will only give you records only.

```
{
    **"_id": ObjectId("58c7da2adaa8d031ea699fff")** 
    "type": "products",
    "products": {
        "Intel® Core™ i9-9980XE Extreme Edition": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 2457,
            "catalog_id": "1"
        },
        "Intel® Core™ i9-9980HK": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 1548,
            "catalog_id": "1"
        },
        "AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2990WX": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 500,
            "catalog_id": "2"
        },
        "Baikalel Ectronics BE-M1000": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 128,
            "catalog_id": "3"
        },
        "GeForce RTX 2080 Ti": {
            "description": null,
            "price": 2048,
            "catalog_id": "5"
        }   
    }
}
```